# Как строго типизировать элементы массива?

Tags: javascript, массивы, typescript

Есть массив:  `[ '2017/07/12', 100, 200, 10 ]`, следующего типа: `(string | number)[]`.
Но первый элемент массива всегда будет строка. Можно ли с помощью TypeScript строго прописать что 1-й элемент строка, а остальные(не известно сколько) числа?

Comment: У вас, очевидно, это семантически иная структура, нежели массив, поэтому правильно будет использовать объект.

Comment: На определенный запрос к серверу он возвращает ответ в виде массива

Comment: Тогда стоит этот массив приводить в удобоваримый вид (к соответствующему объекту) и работать с ним. Все равно валидировать сторонние данные сами по себе не имеет смысла.

Comment: Я вас понял, спасибо!